# setting status code in header php , not working for 442?

Tags: php, ajax, curl, yii, header

I am calling my rest with CURL php and setting response  header like:

```
 header('Status',true,422);
```

and when printing status I get `422`.

but when I set header like:

```
 header('Status',true,440);
```

I get `500` code in response.

I don't know why is it happening.

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: You have to make sure nothing is returned before the "header" statement. Are you sure 440 is valid for all web servers? I think it has something to do with microsoft.

Comment: @inneedofhelp I am not sure about it weather 440 is valid for all the services or not.How can I know about it?

Comment: I would suggest googling it, sorry I don't have the answer ready.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't return HTTP Code headers in this way. There is dedicated function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

```
<?php
http_response_code(422);
http_response_code(440);
?>
```

Additionally, make sure you don't return anything (e.g. by `echo`) before calling these commands.

Comment: @y221 thanks for resposne. but 440 is not working . Is there is any problem with YII framework with this code or nay other reason?